# Vendors dir and Magento 2 themes

Tags: magento2, theme

In all Magento 2 courses and tutorials recommended to create vendor and then theme in the `/app/design/frontend/VENDORNAME/THEMENAME`.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html for example.
But luma and blank theme are located in `/vendors/magento/theme-frontend-luma` and `/vendors/magento/theme-frontend-blank`.

Should and may we place theme in vendors? 
When and why we should do so?
If I place new theme it will not be added to DB. Is there any installation procedure, that differs from creation in `/app/design/frontend/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that you build your theme in app/design/frontend/VENDORNAME/THEMENAME  then package it using composer and store it in a repository of your choice.  This can be git based or a composer repository private or public.

Then you can add this package to a new install of Magento 2 and install it in the /vendor/ directory.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html

If you use git clone to install the development version of Mage2 you will find that all code is stored under /app/.

Answer (score 1):

**vendors** directory is about all the code that wasn't done by you, it's the core & community code. You must never edit or put anything in the vendor directory.